# Find the power series of $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ in $x_0=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, cauchy-product

In 1st Semester Calculus book I found an exercise that asks me to find the above power series of the function at the point $x_0 = 0$ using the geometric series formula and the Cauchy-Product. So far I've calculated:

$$ f(x)= \frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{\frac{x}{x}}{\frac{x+1}{x}}= \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$$
Then with the use of the geometric series formula I've calculated:

because $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{q^n}= \frac{1}{1-q} $$
with $q=(-\frac{1}{x})$
that

$$   f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-\frac{1}{x})^n}$$
and then by setting $n=-k$

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{-k}x^k} $$
I've ended up with the above series, which I would say that looks like a power sum but I am not sure if it is the correct answer due to the fact that I did not use the Cauchy-Product. Therefore any insight on the problem would be appreciated.

Edit: Some corrections as stated in the comments.
The way of setting n=-k is apparently wrong cause it gives an entirely different sum.

Comment: There are many errors in what you did. When you set $n=-k$ that would give a sum for $k=0,-1,-2,...$. Also $(-1/x)^{n}=(-1/x)^{-k}=(-1)^kx^k$, not $-x^k$. Use that $\frac{x}{x+1}=1-\frac{1}{1+x}$

Comment: @logarithm Thanks for the corrections, I'll edit them on my question. Shouls I use the fact that $ \frac{x}{x+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+x} $ to apply Cauchy-Product?

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is *not* a power series.

Note that$$\frac x{x+1}=x\times(1-x+x^2-x^2+\cdots)=x-x^2+x^3-x^4+\cdots$$if $\lvert x\rvert<1$.

Answer (score 1):

for $| x|<1$
$$\frac{x}{x+1}=1-\frac{1}{1+x}=1-(1-x+x^2-x^3+...)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can straight-forwardly use the geometric series :

$$\frac{1}{1+w} = \sum_{n =0}^\infty (-1)^nw^n, \; |w| < 1$$

You are expanding around zero so you have that $|x| <1 $ and simply enough, it is :

$$\frac{x}{1+x} = x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^{n+1}$$